# Сделать мультиязычные поля в админке Opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart3.x

Есть в админке Opencart 3, в настройках Магазина поле "Режим работы". Мне понадобилось сделать это поле мультиязычным. Решил сделать по примеру других страниц.

Файл admin\view\template\setting\setting.twig.
Нахожу код этого поля

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-open"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tab-general" title="{{ help_open }}"> {{ entry_open }}</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea name="config_open" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open" class="form-control">{{ config_open }}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Добавляю к нему {% for language in languages %}, картинки флажков, и ID языка. Получается так:

```
              {% for language in languages %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-open{{ language.language_id }}"><img src="language/{{ language.code }}/{{ language.code }}.png" title="{{ language.name }}" /><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tab-general" title="{{ help_open }}"> {{ entry_open }}</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea name="config_open{{ language.language_id }}" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open{{ language.language_id }}" class="form-control">{{ config_open }}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
```

В админке появилось два поля под каждый язык. Но когда ввожу в него данные и сохраняю, после сохранения информация в этих полях пропадает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сравниваю с другими мультиязычными полями и в шаблоне и в контроллере все одинаково. Не вижу разницы, между моим творением и стандартными мультиязычными полями. Но раз не работает, значит что-то упускаю. Подскажите пожалуйста что именно.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Поменял textarea на input, теперь сохраняется, но не выводится во фронт энд.

```
<input type="text" name="config_open[{{ language.language_id }}][title]" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open{{ language.language_id }}" value="{{ config_open[language.language_id] ? config_open[language.language_id].title }}" class="form-control" />
```

В контроллере фронт энда вывожу так. Пока был один язык, все выводилось

```
$data['open'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_open'));
```

В итоге дает такую ошибку: Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/fastuser/data/www/localstite.loc/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Помогли на другой площадке. Вот, что нужно было сделать. Сначала в файле контролера админки отредактировать код вывода этой переменной и добавить языковую переменную.

Вместо этого

```
        if (isset($this->request->post['config_open'])) {
            $data['config_open'] = $this->request->post['config_open'];
        } else {
            $data['config_open'] = $this->config->get('config_open');
        }
```

Пишем это

```
$this->load->model('localisation/language');
    $languages = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();
        
            foreach ($languages as $language) {
                if (isset($this->request->post['config_open' . $language['language_id']])) {
                    $data['config_open'][$language['language_id']] = $this->request->post['config_open' . $language['language_id']];
                } else {
                    $data['config_open'][$language['language_id']] = $this->config->get('config_open' . $language['language_id']);
                }   
            }
```

Потом в шаблоне админки вместо этого

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-open"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tab-general" title="{{ help_open }}"> {{ entry_open }}</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea name="config_open" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open" class="form-control">{{ config_open }}</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Пишем это

```
              {% for language in languages %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-open{{ language.language_id }}"><img src="language/{{ language.code }}/{{ language.code }}.png" title="{{ language.name }}" /><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#tab-general" title="{{ help_open }}"> {{ entry_open }}</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="config_open{{ language.language_id }}" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open{{ language.language_id }}" value="{% if config_open[language.language_id] %}{{ config_open[language.language_id] }}{% endif %}" class="form-control" />                   
                    </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
```

В контролере фронт энда выводим это так

```
$data['open'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_open' . $this->config->get('config_language_id')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="config_open[{{ language.language_id }}]" rows="5" placeholder="{{ entry_open }}" id="input-open{{ language.language_id }}" class="form-control">
    {{ config_open[language.language_id] }} // [title] не нужен, это лишняя вложенность
</textarea>
```

Значение любого поля группы настроек в `opencart` с префиксом `config_` в имени сохраняется в таблице `setting` с типом `text`. Это логично, т.к. все настройки это по сути строки. Иногда туда записываются массивы, для чего в классе модели `ModelSettingSetting` (`admin/model/setting.php`) предусмотрена логика [сериализации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) данных.

Когда вы привели `textarea` `config_open` к виду поля с локализацией, в модель, при сохранении, в `$this->request->post['config_open']` стал прилетать массив, в котором ключи - `id` языков, значения - контент `config_open`

Далее, при выборке этих данных в контроллере фронта, вы предсказуемо стали получать не строку, как раньше, а [десериализованный](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php) массив.

Поле `config_open` в админке имеет тип `textarea`, что подразумерает возможность сохранять строку с переносами, которые при сохранении переводятся в сивмолы (`\n\r`) В данной строчке `nl2br($this->config->get('config_open'));` в контроллере фронта применяется функция [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php), преобразующая сивмолы переноса строки в html (`<br/>`) и на вход она ожидает строку, но получает массив, о чём php прямо и сообщает:

> Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 **to be string, array given** in /var/www/fastuser/data/www/localstite.loc/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 81

Соответственно, необходимо менять логику получения/обработки настройки, получаемой через `$this->config->get('config_open')`

```
$data['open'] = nl2br($this->config->get('config_open')[$this->config->get('config_language_id')]);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не помогло. Также не сохраняется. Я чуть-чуть по шаманил. Стало сохраняться. Но теперь во фронт энд не выводится. Отредактирую сейчас вопрос, чтобы показать, что сделал.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Но все равно выдает ошибки. В шаблоне админки внес ваши изменения с textarea, в итоге в полях "Время работы" в админке появляется ошибка, вместо моих данных: `<b>Notice</b>: Array to string conversion in <b>/var/www/fastuser/data/www/localsite.loc/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>443</b>Array` Если добавляю `title`, то данные сохраняются нормально. Когда в контроллер фронтэнда добавил ваш код `$data['open'].... `, то на сайте получаю такую ошибку: `Notice: Undefined index: ru-ru in.....`

Comment: добавляя title вы лишь углубляете массив. это нормальный подход для сгруппированных данных. Но в вашем случае необходим только код языка, который становится индексом в массиве данных, сериализующемся при сохранении в setting под кодом config_open. И при десериализации на фронте - $this->config->get('config_open')[$this->config->get('config_language_id')]

Comment: Я понимаю, но без него поля в админке дают ошибку. А с ним данные сохраняются. В чем тогда может быть дело?